# Saving Lists of Data Angular and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have add one input to the list of items but I want many input add to the same $id. How to do it.
I can not deal with it. I was looking for another solution but everything was pounding me errors

My app.js

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute','firebase']);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/List', {
  templateUrl: 'list.html',
  controller: 'ListController'
      }).
      when('/Zarzad', {
  templateUrl: 'zarzad.html',
  controller: 'ListController'
      }).
      otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/List'
      });
}]);

sampleApp.controller('ListController', function($scope,$firebase) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://<my url>.firebaseio.com/');
  var sync = $firebase(ref);
  $scope.projects = sync.$asArray();

  $scope.addMessage = function(data) {
   $scope.projects.$add({data: data});
  }
});
```

My hmtl

```
<form ng-submit="addMessage(newMessageText)">
      <input ng-model="newMessageText" />
      <button type="submit">add message</button>
</form>
```

When I add another input I don`t know how corect write code for a many input. I tried something like this:

```
sampleApp.controller('ListController', function($scope,$firebase) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://<my url>.firebaseio.com/');
  var sync = $firebase(ref);
  $scope.projects = sync.$asArray();

  $scope.addMessage = function(text,data) {
    $scope.projects.$add({text: text, data: data});
  }
});
```

And html like this:

```
<form ng-submit="addMessage(newMessageText)">
      <input ng-model="newMessageText" name="text" />
      <input ng-model="newMessageData" name="data" />
      <button type="submit">add message</button>
</form>
```

And this is a error:

```
Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'data'
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Ba (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js:11:54)
    at Ba (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js:12:221)
    at Aa (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js:10:410)
    at D.E.set (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js:147:98)
    at Object.c.$push (https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js:7:6889)
    at Object.c.$add (https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js:7:516)
    at g.$scope.addMessage (http://localhost/test/js/app.js:25:21)
    at http://localhost/test/js/angular.min.js:179:263
    at http://localhost/test/js/angular.min.js:204:178
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Your original example here almost works. The undefined error is because your addMessage method expects two arguments (text and data) but the addMessage call is only passing one argument addMessage(newMessageText). So as indicated, data is undefined. You cannot set undefined in Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
app.js

```
$scope.addTodo = function () {
    var newData = $scope.newData.trim();
    var newGodz = $scope.newGodz.trim();
    var newTemat = $scope.newTemat.trim();

    $scope.projects.$add({
      data: newData,
      godz: newGodz,
      temat: newTemat
    });

    $scope.newData = '';
    $scope.newGodz = '';
    $scope.newTemat = '';
  };
```

And html is:

```
<form id="todo-form" ng-submit="addTodo()">
      <input type="text" id="new-data" placeholder="Data..." ng-model="newData" autofocus />
      <input type="text" id="new-godz" placeholder="Godzina..." ng-model="newGodz" autofocus /><br />
      <textarea id="new-temat" placeholder="Temat spotkania..." ng-model="newTemat" autofocus rows="4" width="430px;"></textarea><br />
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="submit">Dodaj pozycję</button>
</form>
```